# Template type name at runtime

Tags: c++

This is more of a curiosity question than an actual need. The code is below and here is the question:

```
// header file
class IRNode {
virtual void imple() =0;
}

// one and only derivative of IRNode
template<typename T>
class BaseIRNode : public IRNode { 
// .. some code
void imple() {}
};

// a library function    
IRNode* some_fun() {
return new BaseIRNode<int>(); // just for example, assume we dont know this!
}

// my code
IRNode* myObj = some_func(); 
// I wonder what template T was used to construct BaseIRNode concrete object
// how can I find that out ?
```

UPDATE: so I skipped some code in order to make it simpler, but it seems I omitted too much code.

Comment: `BaseIRNode` is the name of a template for classes, not of a class. So your code just does not work.

Comment: As written, your code doesn't compile. Can you clarify what you really want?

Comment: "Know what type". How do you want this information represented in your program?

Answer (score 2):

That won't compile because `BaseIRNode` is a class template, not a class. You need to make `some_fun` a function template, then you can use the deduce the template parameter from the argument type and operate on that:

```
template <typename T>
void some_fun(BaseIRNode<T>* node) {
    //some stuff with T
}
```